# Start position gyroscope camera unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, accelerometer, gyroscope

I have a 360 video inside a sphere in my unity scene, and I'm using a gyro script so the user can rotate around and watch the movie, the problem is there is a person in the movie and I want the camera to start at the person's position, not the mobile's position, but the way I'm trying to do it is not working:

```
public class Gyro : MonoBehaviour
{


    void Start()
    {
        if (SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope)
        {
            Input.gyro.enabled = true;
        }


            GameObject cameraParent = new GameObject("camParent");
            cameraParent.transform.position = this.transform.position;
            this.transform.parent = cameraParent.transform;
            cameraParent.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, 90);

    }


    void Update()
    {


            Quaternion cameraRotation = new Quaternion(Input.gyro.attitude.x, Input.gyro.attitude.y, -Input.gyro.attitude.z, -Input.gyro.attitude.w);
            this.transform.localRotation = cameraRotation;


    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
void Start()
{
        Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
        initialYAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        Input.gyro.enabled = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(calibra){
            CalibrateYAngle();
            calibra = false;
        }
        ApplyGyroRotation();
        ApplyCalibration();
    }



    public void CalibrateYAngle()
    {
        calibrationYAngle = appliedGyroYAngle - initialYAngle; // Offsets the y angle in case it wasn't 0 at edit time.
    }

    void ApplyGyroRotation()
    {
        transform.rotation = Input.gyro.attitude;
        transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 180f, Space.Self); // Swap "handedness" of quaternion from gyro.
        transform.Rotate(90f, 180f, 0f, Space.World); // Rotate to make sense as a camera pointing out the back of your device.
        appliedGyroYAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y; // Save the angle around y axis for use in calibration.
    }

    void ApplyCalibration()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0f, -calibrationYAngle, 0f, Space.World); // Rotates y angle back however much it deviated when calibrationYAngle was saved.
    }
```

Comment: Are you doing the-same thing as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46935419/3785314) person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       Quaternion cameraRotation = new Quaternion(Input.gyro.attitude.x, Input.gyro.attitude.y, -Input.gyro.attitude.z, -Input.gyro.attitude.w);
       this.transform.localRotation = cameraRotation;
```

With that you only assign your giroscope position to your camera, if you want the camera to start from precise position, you need to add/substract the difference from the last frame and the current frame to your current position