# How to enable gyroscope camera at current device orientation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions, gyroscope

I would like to enable gyro controlled camera onButtonClick event but I want it to start at the camera's current position.  Currently when the gyro gets enabled it moves the camera off to a new position (probably the devices current gyro rotation) rather than leaving it where it is and gyro-ing from that point.

Hope I'm making sense, but basically I don't want the user to notice any change in what they are seeing in the game (ie. camera controlled by gyro but not that user would notice that change). Here's the code I'm using:

```
void Update () 
{
    Quaternion attitudeFix = new Quaternion (-gyro.attitude.x, -gyro.attitude.z, -gyro.attitude.y, gyro.attitude.w);
    Quaternion offsetRotation =  initialGyroRotation * attitudeFix;
    rotation = initialRotation * offsetRotation;
    transform.rotation = rotation;
}

public void EnableGyro() 
{
    initialGyroRotation = Input.gyro.attitude;
    initialRotation = transform.rotation;

    Debug.Log("initialRotation: " + initialRotation.ToString());
    Debug.Log("transform.rotation: " + transform.rotation.ToString());
    Debug.Log("initialGyroRotation: " + initialGyroRotation.ToString());
}
```

**

**EDIT:** Here's a screen of exactly how I want the view to look as the user is holding their device in front of their face (portrait) AND heading north.  Regardless of the orientation of the device when the app starts, this is how it should look when heading north with phone in portrait orientation (again as the user is looking through the phone).

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
Tests were getting confusing so I put the code back to exactly how your solution suggests.  There is still a slight problem, but it seems like this script is very close.  The main problem is the screen doesn't look like the above pic when I run each test, starting the app with the device on strange angles.  It really shouldn't matter what angle the device is when the app is started, it needs to look like the above screen when pointing north and portrait.

I need to do more tests, and will do so with a new/clean project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the offset camera position in the `Awake` or `Start` function. In the `Update` function, apply that offset value to the value from the gyro sensor.

It looks like you already know offset should be used but you are not doing that the right way. The confusing part is getting the offset which requires subtracting the current camera rotation from the gyro sensor value.

To subtract a `Quaternion` multiply the `Inverse` not just the `Quaternion`:

`Quaternion = Quaternion *`[`Quaternion.Inverse`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Inverse.html)

To add a `Quaternion` multiply the `Quaternion`:

```
Quaternion = Quaternion * Quaternion.
```

---

This is what your code should look like:

```
Quaternion offset;

void Awake()
{
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
}

void Start()
{
    //Subtract Quaternion
    offset = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(GyroToUnity(Input.gyro.attitude));
}

void Update()
{
    GyroModifyCamera();
}

void GyroModifyCamera()
{
    //Apply offset
    transform.rotation = offset * GyroToUnity(Input.gyro.attitude);
}

private static Quaternion GyroToUnity(Quaternion q)
{
    return new Quaternion(q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code did exactly what it was supposed to do.  Now that I have that working, of course it exposed other problems I'm having with my implementation of gyro on the camera and compass on a separate game object.  I'd like to know your thoughts on if you think it's possible to setup a camera that does gyro on 2 axis (X/Z) and compass on another game object that does the remaining 1 axis (Y).  Should I start another question?

Comment: This is a whole another issue and question. You can create a new question on this. Make sure to be clear on what you are asking and provide what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks Programmer, here's my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943868/gyroscope-with-compass-help-needed

Comment: Programmer the script above works great, but I need to rotate what I'm seeing by 90 degrees (not sure how or what axis).  Currently the "view" I need works when looking at the device flat on a desk.  But I want the user to view/hold the device portrait in front of their face.  No other change is needed, so how can I add this to the above?

Comment: If you can add screenshot of what you are currently seeing and then another screenshot of what you expect, I will be willing to mess with that code and see if I can fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the look Programmer.  I've edited the OP to include 2 screens and the script.

Answer (score 0):

I hade trouble with this and it wasn't working in build this is what I found and this script has worked.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GyroMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    //Movement
    [SerializeField] float speed = 3.3f;
    private float rotspeed = 90f;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    [SerializeField] private CharacterController controller;

    //Rotation
    private float _initialYAngle = 0f;
    private float _appliedGyroYAngle = 0f;
    private float _calibrationYAngle = 0f;
    private Transform _rawGyroRotation;
    private float _tempSmoothing;

    //settings
    private float _smoothing = 0.1f;

    private void Update(){
      //Movement
      //Vector3 move = new Vector3 (Input.acceleration.x * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, -Input.acceleration.z * speed * Time.deltaTime);
      //Vector3 rotMovement = transform.TransformDirection(move);
      //controller.Move(rotMovement);

      //Rotation
      ApplyGyroRotation();
      ApplyCalibration();
      transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, _rawGyroRotation.rotation, _smoothing);

    }

    private IEnumerator Start(){
      Input.gyro.enabled = true;
      Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
      _initialYAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;

      _rawGyroRotation = new GameObject("GyroRaw").transform;
      _rawGyroRotation.position = transform.position;
      _rawGyroRotation.rotation = transform.rotation;
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
      StartCoroutine (CalibrateYAngle());
    }

    private IEnumerator CalibrateYAngle(){
      _tempSmoothing = _smoothing;
      _smoothing = 1f;
      _calibrationYAngle = _appliedGyroYAngle - _initialYAngle;
      yield return null;
      _smoothing = _tempSmoothing;
    }

    private void ApplyGyroRotation(){
      _rawGyroRotation.rotation = Input.gyro.attitude;
      _rawGyroRotation.Rotate(0f, 0f, 180f, Space.Self);
      _rawGyroRotation.Rotate(90f, 180f, 0f, Space.World);
      _appliedGyroYAngle = _rawGyroRotation.eulerAngles.y;
    }

    private void ApplyCalibration(){
      _rawGyroRotation.Rotate(0f, -_calibrationYAngle, 0f, Space.World);
    }

    public void SetEnabled (bool value){
      enabled = true;
      StartCoroutine(CalibrateYAngle());
    }
}
```