# Android headtracking with gyroscope, initial direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm trying to implement android tracking in Unity via `Input.gyro`. What I'm basically trying to do is have my guy's up-down (pitch) head movement and body turning (yaw) control through the gyroscope. It works insofar as when I start the game with the phone straight ahead of me this is taken as the reference point and everything works as expected. However, when I start the game with the phone lying down, the game assumes that's the planar field and when I rotate the phone to hold it out in front of me the game looks up.

Is there some way to figure out in absolute values whether the phone is lying down or on it's side? I've tried storing the initial `Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.y` but that doesn't seem to be doing much of anything.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class GyroTracker: MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform head;

    public float clampAngleUp = 80.0f;
    public float clampAngleDown = 52.0f;
    private float rotY = 0.0f; // rotation around the up/y axis
    private float rotX = 0.0f; // rotation around the right/x axis

    void Start() {
        Input.compensateSensors = true;
        Input.gyro.enabled = true;

        rotY = Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.y;
        rotX = Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.x;

    }
    void FixedUpdate() {

        rotY -= Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.y;
        rotX -= Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.x;
        rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, -clampAngleUp, clampAngleDown);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotY, 0); // Rotate bodys Y
        head.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, 0); // Rotate head X
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry Programmer but the code suggested in your answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935419/how-to-enable-gyroscope-camera-at-current-device-orientation) is working even less than what I currently have. If I start the app with the phone facing down, the Z axis is rotated 90 degrees (meaning the horizon is suddenly vertical)

See https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spassvogel/headtracking/master/Assets/thumbnail_Screenshot_20171206-120142.jpg.

I've pushed the code to https://github.com/spassvogel/headtracking. This is using your exact example. Unity 2017.2.0f3 and Galaxy S8 btw

Comment: Oh I realise now that this is because of the phone being in portrait mode. When I fix the orientation in Build Settings it no longer flips the z axis. But again, when I start the app with the phone facing down, my orientation is wrong (i.e. I start off seeing the block whereas I should be seeing the floor)

Comment: I was able to get workable situation by loading Google Cardboard (        UnityEngine.XR.XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName("cardboard") ) 

then I could set camera rotation via             head.transform.localRotation = InputTracking.GetLocalRotation( XRNode.CenterEye );


For me this is an acceptable solution. Still, I consider it a work-around and it might not be appropriate for everyone. I'm keeping this question open.