# Detect initial orientation for Gyroscope Camera, but heading only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, orientation, gyroscope

So I'm using a script I found on here ([How to enable gyroscope camera at current device orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935419/how-to-enable-gyroscope-camera-at-current-device-orientation)) BUT I only want this initial device orientation to affect the heading.

```
Quaternion offset;

void Awake()
{
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
}

void Start()
{
    //Subtract Quaternion
    offset = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(GyroToUnity(Input.gyro.attitude));
}

void Update()
{
    GyroModifyCamera();
}

void GyroModifyCamera()
{
    //Apply offset
    transform.rotation = offset * GyroToUnity(Input.gyro.attitude);
}

private static Quaternion GyroToUnity(Quaternion q)
{
    return new Quaternion(q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
}
```

For the backstory, I have a few interior renderings, with a gyro control to look around the space. I don't want to affect the entire world orientation, I just want them to be facing in the "correct" direction, in terms of the best view of the space. (If not, it just depends on how the device is oriented and its common to jump into a space looking at a random, uninteresting corner of the room.)

With the script above, it resets the camera on all three axes (and therefore the entire world orientation), so if the user is holding the tablet at an unusual angle, then things get really weird.

Here's a quick image to assist the explanation:

[image: camera angle issue]

I always want the initial view to be aligned with the green arrow, not something random like the red arrow. But just the heading, it's OK to be looking at the floor or ceiling as long as the heading is right in that sweet spot of the room.

Thanks!

Comment: Found a script that does exactly this, if anyone else stumbles upon the thread: https://gist.github.com/kormyen/a1e3c144a30fc26393f14f09989f03e1/10f98c612fc370a23c9520bf77820707eb27f828